# Разбить фрейм пополам

Tags: java, gui

Привет! Хочу сделать аналог тотала, для этого нужно расположить 2 панели на фрейме(левый, правый). Делаю с помощью бордерлэйаута(один EAST, другой WEST) - когда размер фрейма не на весь экран, то выглядит как надо, а когда делаю его на весь экран то CENTER себя показывает... а он мне не нужен... 
Подскажите как скомпоновать 2 панели друг к другу, чтобы они был в равных долях от размеров общего фрейма?

Answer (score 0):

точно...сразу не сообразил... через Грид же можно!

```
frame.getContentPane().add(leftPane, new GridLayout(0,1));
frame.getContentPane().add(rightPane,new GridLayout(0,2));
```